# Facebook Login Graph API returns wrong profile picture URL

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, codenameone

I'm using Facebook graph API by calling [https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/me?access_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&fields=id,email,name,first_name,last_name,gender,age_range,picture.width(512).height(512),locale,link,timezone,updated_time](https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/me?access_token=XXX&fields=id,email,name,first_name,last_name,gender,age_range,picture.width(512).height(512),locale,link,timezone,updated_time) which returns the json response I was expecting. Something like this:

```
{
   "id": "1234567890987654321",
   "email": "xxxxxx\u0040example.com",
   "name": "xxxx xxxx",
   "first_name": "xxxx",
   "last_name": "xxxx",
   "gender": "xxxxx",
   "age_range": {
      "min": 21
   },
   "picture": {
      "data": {
         "height": 720,
         "is_silhouette": false,
         "url": "https://scontent.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p720x720/xxx.jpg?oh=xxx",
         "width": 720
      }
   },
   "locale": "en_US",
   "link": "https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/1234567890987654321/",
   "timezone": xx,
   "updated_time": "2017-05-24T14:00:01+0000"
}
```

However, on calling the `url` child node of the `picture`, nothing was returned. I copied the actual link and paste it in Google Chrome browser and `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN` error is returned.

I checked the image used by the Facebook website, I noticed that it's pointing to a different base url: [https://scontent.fjnb2-1.fna.fbcdn.net](https://scontent.fna.fbcdn.net), while mine is pointing to https://scontent.fna.fbcdn.net. The returned url on graph is missing `.fjnb2-1` and it works when I added it.

Is this a known bug on Facebook Graph API?

Is it ok to change the base url to include the missing part?

Any other way to fix this issue without running into another issue later when Facebook decided to change the return url?

Comment: smells like a bug. report it to fb.

Comment: Seems like I'm not alone. On checking https://developers.facebook.com/bugs and searched for `picture url` I got tons of bugs reported about this already. That helps.

Comment: Hi @Diamond, have you solved this problem?

Comment: Not yet. Waiting for Facebook to fix the issue, keeping my eyes on it and will update my answer once it's done.

Comment: It works. Facebook developers have fixed.

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug which has already been reported by many developers on [https://developers.facebook.com/bugs](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/) and I believe the Facebook team is working on resolving this.

## Edit:

I can confirm that this issue has been resolved by Facebook Dev Team now.